# How to find in sorted set an element which is just below a certain value

Tags: redis

First, I am new to Redis. Well let's say I have done:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd subs:x 0 0
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd subs:x 500 500
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd subs:x 1000 1000
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd subs:x 5000 5000
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd subs:x 10000 10000
```

And I want to find an element that is just above the value 2000 and just below.

Above is simple and easy:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE subs:x 2000 +inf LIMIT 0 1
1) "5000"
```

But how to find an element below in simple way?

1) I know I can do:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE subs:x -inf 2000 LIMIT 2 1
1) "1000"
```

But I have to know before running this command that offset is 2 so in general I have to find offset first.

2) Or I can find ZRANK and then move one step backward:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANK subs:x 5000
(integer) 3
127.0.0.1:6379>  ZRANGE subs:x 2 2
1) "1000"
```

So my question is there a simple way to get element just below a certain value?

Comment: Like above, but for below, use [`ZREVRANGEBYSCORE`](http://redis.io/commands/ZREVRANGEBYSCORE), you should.

Comment: Thanks, `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE subs:x 2000 -inf LIMIT 0 1` works. Please post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Like above, but for below, use `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE`, you should.

Translation from Yoda-speak:

Redis actually features a command that does just what you're looking for - [`ZREVRANGEBYSCORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebyscore). `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE` does the same thing as `ZRANGEBYSCORE` but uses reverse ordering (as the "REV" in its name suggests).

That would allow you to get the "below 2000" member easily with just one call, as you've shown in your comment. May the force be with you.